# Why cannot replace incrementAndGet() with Get() for byte sequence generator?

Tags: java, concurrency

My question actually based on the best answer from here: [what is wrong with this thread-safe byte sequence generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384875/what-is-wrong-with-this-thread-safe-byte-sequence-generator/7387782#7387782)

Why is this solution NOT thread-safe:

```
public class ByteGeneratorNotThreadSafe {
    private static final int INITIAL_VALUE = Byte.MIN_VALUE - 1;

    private final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(INITIAL_VALUE);

    public byte nextValue() {
        int next = counter.incrementAndGet();
        if (next > Byte.MAX_VALUE) {
            synchronized (counter) {
                next = counter.get(); //this one is changed
                if (next > Byte.MAX_VALUE) {
                    counter.set(INITIAL_VALUE); //also removed +1
                    next = INITIAL_VALUE; //also removed +1
                }
            }
        }
        return (byte) next;
    }
}
```

when this below IS thread-safe?

```
public class ByteGenerator2 {
    private static final int INITIAL_VALUE = Byte.MIN_VALUE - 1;

    private final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(INITIAL_VALUE);

    public byte nextValue() {
        int next = counter.incrementAndGet();
        if (next > Byte.MAX_VALUE) {
            synchronized (counter) {
                next = counter.incrementAndGet();
                if (next > Byte.MAX_VALUE) {
                    counter.set(INITIAL_VALUE + 1);
                    next = INITIAL_VALUE + 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return (byte) next;
    }
}
```

The only difference I see, that I remove extra increment by replacing incrementAndGet() with get() and remove +1 for initial state. Why was it ruin safeness?

Comment: `AtomicInteger.updateAndGet` is probably more appropriate here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The counter object is incremented outside the 'synchronized' lock (very first line of the `nextValue` method invokes `incrementAndGet`).

If you have 20 threads, the `AtomicInteger` starts out at 0, and each thread calls, simultaneously: `counter.incrementAndGet()`, then afterwards the atomicinteger holds value 20. Guaranteed.

Whereas if you have 20 threads and they all do, simultaneously: `int c = counter.get(); counter.set(c + 1);` then after all is done, the atomicinteger might be 20. Or 5. or 18. or 1.

The reason is rather simple: 20 threads all run the .get() line, all see zero, 20 threads all calculate '0+1', which is 1, and then 20 threads all set, in turn, the atomic integer to 1. Or even: one thread sees 0, gets pre-empted, 19 other threads play nice, increment the atomicinteger nicely from 0 to 19, and then finally that original thread continues on, calculates '0+1', and sets the atomicinteger to it, bringing us back to '.. and after all that the value is 1'.

Here the synchronization helps, but given that incrementing is occurring outside, you can still get the problem of the one thread that is inside the synchronized block reading, say, '5', then another 3 threads hitting the incrementAndGet outside of the synchronized block, making it 8, and then the original thread also setting the atomicinteger back to 6, thus you have 'missed' an bunch of increments.